# How to reference a library css file in your project in angular

Tags: angular

I'm a complete angular noob.

I know how to create the component based css files but how do I reference a css file from a template?

For example I have an animations.css file from a template, but want to reference it in my header in my index.html file.

There is an index.html file in the root of the project.  Do i just created a css folder in the same directory and reference it from the index.html?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in angular to reference yours css file.

Option 1: mention it via CDN in index.html itself

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Option 2: use it as an [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) statement in your global styles.css file which is created when your Angular project is generated by default or in your app.module.ts

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Option 3: You can link it in the angular-cli.json as a css reference to a particular component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.css'],
})
```

So a file named foo.component.css will hold all the css references to foo.component.html

For more reference [Angular Style Docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Comment: Note that we can add as many CSS files as we want to `styleUrls` since it is an array.